# Show more button: With PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have been learning PHP/Mysql for a while. But don't yet know enough to do this.

I have table "cities"

I am using this query `"SELECT * FROM cities GROUP BY country"`

I can output the results with

```
<?php do { ?>
<div class="cities">
<h4><a href="/cities/?id=<?php echo $row_cities['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_cities['city']; ?></a></h4>
</div>
<?php } while ($row_cities = mysql_fetch_assoc($cities)); ?>
```

The group by country in the select query forces the results to only have one city for each
country.

I want to create a "show more button/link" that once clicked will show all cities for each country.

This isn't very difficult somthing like this would do the trick.

```
<a href="/cities/?country=<?php echo $row_cities['country']; ?>">Show More</a>
```

However, I would like this show more button to be more "sophisticated".

a). The show more button should only appear if results of each city is greater than 1.

b). Show More text should also contain a number indicating the number of results example
    Show 1 More, Show 2 More Show 3 More etc.

Your help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do

```
SELECT cities.id, cities.country, cities.city, count(*)
    FROM cities
    GROUP BY cities.country
```

The last selected field will hold the number of elements in each group.

Comment: Excellent. That's what I needed. Then I can construct an if and else statement to handle weather the show more button should appear or not.